# How to make a proper fit for data, according to a given equation?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am doing some help to a teacher with Python and he asked me that the data collected be adjusted according to the following equation:

```
f(t) = A*exp(−t/τ ) + C
```

With A and C constants. This is developed to know the half-life of a particle: muon (τ time of life)

My teacher, for the exponential function made the analysis of the data with the QtiPlot software, obtaining the following graph [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTFhf.jpg). Reaching the particle a life time of 2.1 micro seconds, with the following data set, is these: [data](https://shorturl.at/ekEY8)

I never really did anything with functions in python, and I want to do the same histogram, with the curve line adjusted to the function and find 'τ' life time

```
x_data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
y_data = np.arange(1,len(data)+1,1)
t = np.arange(1,len(data),1)
C = 0.9 #for example, since I don't know how the teacher chooses


plt.hist(x_data, bins=200)
plt.gca().set(title='Muon', ylabel='ene');



def test_func(x, y, t, C):
    fun = lambda x, y, t, C: x*np.exp((-y)/(T))+C
    return fun
```

## How can I do the function and show it in the graph next to the histogram?

Comment: Hi Diego, the start looks good. You do not need the `lambda` in the function definition. Actually ,`lambdas` are used to "avoid" `def`. You sghould complete the code including imports to make it work straight away. The check `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Your problem is standard. Also note that this is help page for programming but not a teach the manual page. You could figure all this by a reasonable search in your favourite search engine.

Comment: The data in the link you posted does not look like the graph. Are these the same data set?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes, they are the same, the graph is made with a histogram, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This is what I can currently get

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

t = np.arange(1,len(x_data)+1,1)
C = 1
x_data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

def func(x,y):
    return x*np.exp((-y)/(t))+c

coeff, _ = curve_fit(func,x_data,t)
print(f'{coeff}')
plt.hist(x_data, bins=200)
plt.plot(x_data,func(x_data,t))
plt.show()
```

[**resulting graph**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znBEd.png)

## How can I get the correct adjustment line?

Comment: `func` does not take any parameters, it returns always the same. How can that function be able to adapt to the data? I suggest to read a bit more on python, scipy and curve fitting.